# An Account signing off on all transactions

Tags: rust, transactions, sign

I need to create a program where only 1 wallet signs and pays all transactions.

Example:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SignupUser<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = authority, space = 8 + 40 + 120  + 32)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

In this case, I want my wallet to pay for all the users that will be registered.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Without exposing your secret key, your best options is for the program to have a pool of funds (under the program's authority, typically owned by a PDA), and this pool transfers the user some funds to compensate for the account creation fee.

In your case, user will still be the payer/authority, they will pay the account init fee, then you can transfer them funds from some pool like:

```
    fn transfer_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>> {
        CpiContext::new(
            self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: self.some_pool.to_account_info(),
                to: self.user_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: self.authority_pda.clone(),
            },
        )
    }

    token::transfer(
        ctx.accounts
            .transfer_context()
            .with_signer(&[&authority_pda.authority_seeds()]),
        to_receive,
    )?;
```

Comment: But I want my wallet to pay all the transactions, instead of the user

Comment: Then you would have to expose your secret key, since only the keypair that signs the tx can pay the tx fee and account init fees. A PDA can sign for a transfer, which lets you refund that fee without exposing your key. If you refund the user's fee in the same tx, they won't notice the difference.

Comment: If you absolutely must pay for the transaction fees, and you don't want to expose the private key, you can setup a service, like a web API, which takes a user instruction, and then your secret key sets itself as the fee payer, signs it, and sends it to the chain itself